# How to serve file with specific extension

Tags: file, asp.net-core, stream

I am trying to download a file using `js` from a `.net core` app and i want the server to set the file extension.

I do not know how to set it without using the `File` method:

**What Works**

```
public  FileResult DownloadFileAsync() {
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(FILEPATH, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); 
                this.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                this.Response.ContentLength = stream.Length;
                return File(stream, "application/force-download", "data2.txt");
                                                                          ^                                                     
        }
```

**What i am trying to make it work**

```
public async Task DownloadAsync(long id) {
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(FILEPATH, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
                this.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                this.Response.ContentLength = stream.Length;

                await stream.CopyToAsync(this.Response.Body);

            }
        }
```

**P.S** How can i set the file extension without using the `File` method like in the first case.
Is there another field in the `response` where i can set the `type` of the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the content-disposion property of Reponse  worked for me, in this case the file downloaded will be named "filename.jpg":

'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="filename.jpg"'